# с помощью for of перебрать массив a5 и возвратить новый массив куда входят элементы из a5 большe 7?

Tags: javascript

```js
let a5 = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 23, 17];

let out5 = document.querySelector(".out-5");

function f5() {
  let arr = a5.filter(item => item > 7);
  out5.innerHTML = `${arr} `;
  return arr;
}

document.querySelector('.b-5').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.out-5').innerHTML = f5();
});
```

я решил этот вопрос таким способом, подскажите как его решить с помощью for of ?, заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как его решить с помощью `for of` ?

в чем сложность использования указанного цикла?

```js
function x(arr, val){
   let result = [];
   for(v of arr){
      if(v > val) result.push(v);
   } 
   return result;
}


console.log( x([3,4,5,2,1,7,8,2,4,6,8,11,23,17], 7) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так получилось

```
    let a5 = [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 23, 17];

function getNewArray(arr) {
  let res = [];
  
  for(let number of a5) {
    if(number > 7) {
      res.push(number);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(getNewArray([3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 23, 17]))
```